# indesign delete first page in layout

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

How can I delete the first page (right-hand page) in a layout? Used to be you could start a section on page 2 (first left-hand page) then you could delete the first page, but I can't see how to do that anymore.
Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Delete page 1. Layout gets wonky but don't panic. Select new first page. Then Numbering & Section Options -- select Start Page Numbering at: 2 (not 1)

Comment: The alternative I've always used is to simply leave it blank and omit it when exporting the finished PDF.